# orderFrontStandardAboutPanel won't come to front

Tags: objective-c, macos

My app is an OSX status bar app with an "About" menu option in it. The app runs fine and appears as expected in the status bar. I connect the About `menuItem`'s Sent Actions to the File's Owner, specifically to `orderFrontStandardAboutPanel`. The menu item can be clicked with the app is run, and the about panel shows up, but it is always behind the topmost window that is open at the time. Xcode 5, building for OSX 10.8 and 10.9.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to do this in the app delegate, rather than the File's Owner.

In the app delegate:

```
-(IBAction)bringToFront:(id)sender{

    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

    [NSApp orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:self];
}
```

Then sent actions from the `menuItem` to that method.